# Emails sent with the Gmail API are not grouped in threads?

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I am using the `gmail API` for sending emails. This is the function I am using to create an email:

```
    def createEmailNoAttachments(self, send_to_emails, subject_text, main_message_text, msgID=None, inReplyTo=None, html=False):
        try:
            fromEmail = self.from_email_total
            
            
            if (type(main_message_text) == list) or (type(main_message_text) == tuple): 
                total_text = ""
                for line in main_message_text:
                    if type(line) == str: 
                        total_text = total_text + line + "\n"
                main_message_text = total_text
                        
            mimeMessage = MIMEMultipart()
            if type(send_to_emails) == list: 
                mimeMessage['to'] = ", ".join(send_to_emails)
            else: 
                mimeMessage['to'] = send_to_emails

            mimeMessage['from'] = fromEmail
            mimeMessage['subject'] = subject_text
            if inReplyTo != None: 
                mimeMessage["In-Reply-To"] = inReplyTo
                mimeMessage["References"] = inReplyTo
            if msgID != None: 
                mimeMessage['Message-ID'] = msgID
            if html: 
                msg= MIMEText(main_message_text, 'html')
            else: 
                msg= MIMEText(main_message_text, "plain")
            mimeMessage.attach(msg)

            raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(mimeMessage.as_bytes())
            raw = raw.decode()
            body = {'raw': raw}

            return body
        except:
            self.myLogger.error("An error was encountered while attempting to create gmail email")
            tb = traceback.format_exc()
            self.myLogger.exception(tb)
            return False
```

I then send the email with

```
    def gmailAPISendEmail(self, email_message, deleteFromInbox=False, userID="me"):
        try:
            self.refreshGmailService()
            
            self.myLogger.info("Attempting to send email message")

            request = self.service.users().messages().send(userId=userID, body=email_message)
            response = self.executeGmailAPI_withretry(request=request)
            if response == False: 
                self.myLogger.error("An error occurred in executeGmailAPI_withretry while trying to send email message")
                return False
            else:
                try: 
                    responseID = str(response['id'])

                    if deleteFromInbox == True: 
                        delete_result = self.deleteEmail(emailID=responseID)
                        if delete_result == False: 
                            self.myLogger.error(f"An error occurred in deleteEmail with responseID ({responseID})")
                
                    self.myLogger.info("Successfully sent email message with ID (" + responseID +")")
                    return responseID
                except: 
                    return "CouldNotExtractID"
        except:
            self.myLogger.error("An error occurred in gmailAPISendEmail")
            tb = traceback.format_exc()
            self.myLogger.exception(tb)
            return False
```

The problem I am noticing is that similar emails with the same email subject and same sender and recipient are not being grouped under one thread when sent using the above functions (the `gmail API`). In the recipient email inbox, each individual email appears separately, even though they have the same subject and same sender and receiver email addresses.

I believe the next step would be to manually assign `threadid`. However, this is far from ideal, as I would need to incorporate some logic to do all of this.

Before when I used `SMTP`, I didn't have to set a `threadid` or anything like that. When sending emails with `SMTP`, emails would automatically group together based on same email subject and same recipient.

Nothing changed between before and now, except that I am sending the same emails with the `gmail API` in place of `SMTP`.

Why doesn't the `gmail API` behave similar to `SMTP`, even though I am creating the email very similarly? Is there something I can do to have `Gmail` inboxes to group the emails just like `SMTP`, without having to build logic and keeping track of `threadid`s?

Comment: You seem to be confused about what a "thread" means. Messages in a thread are replies to messages earlier in the thread, back to the original message which started the thread. Microsoft has a concept of "thread id" but it's not part of SMTP, or, from what I can find, useful.

Comment: I see, thanks. Email messages that are similar used to automatically be grouped together in Gmail threads. Gmail did that automatically simply because the emails were similar (same subject, similar message, same recipient etc). With SMTP, I did nothing with thread ids. I just sent the email. Gmail would then group the emails together.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue.  In my case, as with the OP, these are not reply messages.  They are simply a series of messages with the same Subject, sender, and recipient.  Messages sent via gmail SMTP server are grouped into a single "thread" in the Gmail Web email client.  Messages sent via the Gmail API are not.  Any progress on this question?

Comment: Whether you assign it or not, each email message you send will have in-relpy-to, references,threadIDs, and possibly other IDs. If you don't assign it, it will be randomly generated. Gmail sees this as a unique ID which does not correspond to any email thread and will therefore appear on its own. SMTP did not have these IDs, and so Gmail did the inference logic. But with specific and defined IDs, Gmail will group based on those IDs.

Answer (score 2):

From [sending](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending)

> If you're trying to send a reply and want the email to thread, make sure that:
>
> - The Subject headers match
> - The References and In-Reply-To headers follow the [RFC 2822](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822#appendix-A.2) standard.
> - For information on sending a message from a draft, see [Creating Drafts](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/drafts).

So you need the message id of the original message you are replying to.  This is not the same as thread id.

```
message['In-Reply-To'] = message_id
message['References'] = message_id
```

Comment: Proper handling of `References:` is to copy the `References:` from the message you are replying to, and add its `Message-Id`, but prune the result if it grows too long, leaving the root `Message-Id` and the latest ones.

Comment: See also https://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html

Comment: @tripleee not sure i understand your point.  Feel free to edit this or open your own answer im happy to delete this if you can explain it better.

Comment: I'm not in a place where I can test a solution. Extending the previous  `References:` by adding another string at the end should be straightforward enough; perhaps leave the pruning of long values as an exercise.